# C#, datetime.parse Error 32510 can not parse

Tags: c#

everyone.
I have a datetime coming back from a music file in the format:
32510
Maybe, it means 1989/01/02

How can i get the datetime.parse function to pick up on this? Ie parse it without erroring? Cheers

Comment: post your current code.

Comment: post some declarative question with code, error and possible ways you tried.

Answer (score 8):

This DateTime(32510) is in double **so we can't simply use datetime.parse** to convert 32510 to DateTime. To convert a double to date we need to use **DateTime.FromOADate** method.

For more details you can go through this MSDN link:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.fromoadate(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Quite often interop dates are stored as integers, so you'll need to convert them to actual dates. See below as an example:

```
var dt = DateTime.FromOADate(32510);
Console.WriteLine(dt);
```

Where the output is:

```
2/01/1989 12:00:00 AM
```

I don't think you can use `DateTime.Parse()` to convert **32510** to **1989/01/02** though.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds me like `Ole Date`, try using [`DateTime.FromOADate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.fromoadate(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
DateTime date = DateTime.FromOADate(32510)
//output - 1/2/1989 12:00:00 AM
```